# Formatando datas para exibição e armazenamento

Tags: android, data, conversão

Neste aplicativo Android, tenho um campo de data na tabela do banco de dados SQLITE, assim definido:

```
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RUNS + " ( " +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL_RUN_DATE + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, " +...
```

Ao inserir um novo registro, ele automaticamente coloca a data como YYYY-MM-DD.

Na hora de exibir, passo a data por este método que a devolve no formato DD/MM/AA. Isso é feito chamando o método a seguir:

```
String strDateToShow(String dateToFormat){
    // format date to display
    SimpleDateFormat formatFrom, formatTo;
    formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formatTo   = new SimpleDateFormat();
    if(dateToFormat != null) {
        try {
            Date mDate = formatFrom.parse(dateToFormat);
            dateToFormat = formatTo.format(mDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(dateToFormat == null){
        dateToFormat = formatTo.format(new Date());
    }
    return stringToSpace(dateToFormat);
}
```

Exemplo: entra 2017-01-26 
         sai 26/01/17

Mais tarde, na hora de atualizar o registro, tento fazer o inverso, mas não está funcionando. Via debug percebi que sempre ocorre exceção na linha comentada a seguir:

```
private String strDateToStore(String dateToFormat){
    // format date
    SimpleDateFormat formatFrom, formatTo;
    formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat();
    formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    if(dateToFormat != null) {
        try {
            Date mDate = formatFrom.parse(dateToFormat); // <-- aqui ocorre a exceção.
            dateToFormat = formatTo.format(mDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(dateToFormat == null){
        dateToFormat = formatTo.format(new Date());
    }
    return stringToSpace(dateToFormat);
}
```

Exemplo: Entra 26/01/17 e sai 26/01/17 quando devia sair 2017-01-26

O formato de exibição pode variar. Se fosse sempre dia/mes/ano, era só deixar explicito, mas o formato deve ser o do lugar onde o aplicativo está sendo usado.

PS. A solução não precisa usar os métodos. Basta converter de e para que está bom.

ATUALIZAÇÃO: Devido ao teor das respostas, cabe esclarecer um pouco mais a situação.

Quando o registro é gerado, a data é inserida automaticamente no formato yyyy-MM-dd, por exemplo, 2017-01-25.
Os registros são mostrados em uma lista. Nesta hora, a data é convertida para o formato de exibição.
Em algum momento, o usuário decide alterar os dados do registro e que vai  atualizar o banco de dados, eu pego a data e converto do formato de exibição, seja qual for, no formato yyyy-MM-dd, que é o cerne da questão proposta.

Algumas observações:

1) os métodos de operações no banco de dados, usam um POJO, por isso eu preciso reformatar a data. Se fosse uma instrução UPDATE (SQL) explicita, eu poderia pular a data e ela seria mantida, mas como  é do tipo

```
database.update(TABLE_RUNS, values, whereClause, null);
```

Tenho que retomar todos os valores.

2) Minha solução de jerico: vou gravar a data original no `tag` da textView da data e na hora de atualizar, em vez `getText()` vou usar `getTag()`. Resolve, mas é um quebra galho. Seria legal (e menos asnice) ter um (ou dois) método(s) universal(ais) pra conversão de/para datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda dos colegas e algumas modificações no código, consegui o efeito desejado.

Este método retorna uma string formatada como data do sistema, a partir de uma string no formato yyyy-MM-dd. Entra 2017-01-26, sai 26-1-17 ou 1-26-17, de acordo com as configurações do aparelho.

```
public String convertDateToShow(String strDate){
    // formato de entrada deve ser 2017-01-17
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    // sem argumentos, pega o formato do sistema para exibir a data
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat();
    // com argumentos formato e locale a saida e sempre a mesma
    //  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US);
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormatIn.parse(strDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return stringToSpace(String.valueOf(dateFormatOut.format(convertedDate)));
}

// stringToSpace() retorna a string a esquerda do primeiro espaço da string passada.
// necessario porque a conversao retorna dd/MM/yy 12:00 hs
private String stringToSpace(String string){

    int spaceIndex = string.indexOf(" ");
    if(spaceIndex > 0) {
        string = string.substring(0, spaceIndex);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Retorna uma string formatada como data no formato yyyy-MM-dd, a partir de uma string formatada como data do sistema. Entra 26-1-17 ou 1-26-17 e sai 2017-26-01

```
public String convertDateToStore(String strDate){
    // formato de entrada do sistema (dd-MM-yy ou MM-dd-yy ou...)
    // sem argumentos, pega o formato do sistema para exibir a data
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat();
    // com argumentos formato e locale a saida e sempre a mesma
    // SimpleDateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormatIn.parse(strDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.valueOf(dateFormatOut.format(convertedDate));
}
```

E zefini.

Answer (score 2):

Este erro acontece porque você não coloca o formato de entrada no SimpleDateFormat, tente alterar a linha abaixo

De:

```
formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat();
```

Para:

```
formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
```

Você também pode utilizar um só método para reutilização do código, ao invés de utilizar dois métodos praticamente iguais:

```
private String strToDate(String dateToFormat, String formatIn, String formatOut){
    // format date
    SimpleDateFormat formatFrom, formatTo;
    formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
    formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat(formatOut);
    if(dateToFormat != null) {
        try {
            Date mDate = formatFrom.parse(dateToFormat); // <-- aqui ocorre a exceção.
            dateToFormat = formatTo.format(mDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(dateToFormat == null){
        dateToFormat = formatTo.format(new Date());
    }
    return stringToSpace(dateToFormat);
}
```

E chamar o mesmo método porém com parâmetros diferentes.

Para leitura:

`String dataLeitura = strToDate(data, "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yy");`

E para escrita:

`String dataEscrita = strToDate(data, "dd/MM/yy", "yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: O formato dd-MM-yy reflete o LOCALE. Não tenho certeza que sempre será este formato. Se tivesse, estaria resolvido. Tem como puxar o formato da data que o aparelho está usando?

Comment: @ReneFreak Deixa eu ver se entendi sua dúvida, na entrada da informação vc tem que pegar o formato configurado no sistema para assim realizar a conversão?

Comment: @ReneFreak, se voce precisar voce pode pegar o DateFormat do sistema com 'DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)' e passar o formato como parâmetro do método.

Comment: o que eu preciso: exibir a data no formato que o usuário espera ver suas datas, seja dd/mm, mm/dd (não dá pra saber isso, antecipadamente). O que sabemos é, como a data é guardada no banco de dados: yyyy-mm-dd. Veja a resposta que eu dei, com as modificações no código que você sugeriu.

Answer (score 1):

O que você tem que observar é que você está entrando com um formato diferente do que você está usando no `SimpleDateFormat()`. Basicamente você tem que usar dois formatos, um de entrada e outro de saída. Para entrada neste seu caso seria `26/01/17` e saída `2017-01-26`, então o parâmetro do método `SimplesDateFormat()` respectivamente seria `dd-MM-yy` de entrada e `yyyy-MM-dd` de saída. Veja o método abaixo como pode ser resolvido o problema:

```
public String convertStringInDate(String str){
    // formato de entrada deve ser 26/01/17 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatInOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormatIn.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.valueOf(dateFormatInOut.format(convertedDate));
}
```

Para mais detalhes, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)<sup>(en)</sup>.

**EDIT**

Em importante definir a localidade para o `SimpleDateFormat`, embora as vezes definido como `getDefault()`, deve-se tomar cuidado pois ele pode não ser apropriado para todos os casos de uso, especialmente dispositivos de leitura de saída. Veja um observação [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)<sup>(en)</sup>:

> A localidade padrão não é apropriada para saída legível por
>   dispositivo. A melhor opção é geralmente `Locale.US` - esta localidade
>   está garantida para estar disponível em todos os dispositivos, e é
>   freqüentemente usado.

Veja mais [detalhes aqui.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: O formato dd-MM-yy reflete o LOCALE. Não tenho certeza que sempre será este formato. Se tivesse, estaria reolvido. Tem como puxar o formato da data que o aparelho está usando?

Comment: @ReneFreak cometi um gafe, corrigi editando a resposta. Tem como puxar sim a localidade que está configurada no seu app, embora ser assunto para outra pergunta, baseado na localidade você tem o formato da data.

Comment: Talvez eu esteja usando o termo errado ao falar em LOCALE. Meu problema é com esta linha: ` SimpleDateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US);` Não com o Locale, que tanto faz, mas eu não tenho certeza de que o formato será dd/MM/yy, pode ser MM/dd/yy ou outro ainda.

Comment: @ReneFreak existe um formato padrão dependendo a localização, Ex.: `yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s`, porém quando você faz `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy", Locale.US)`, você está definindo que quer converter do padrão para esse, e vice versa. Se você define Locale.US, te dá a certeza que sempre virá nesse formato `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` que é o formato Americano. Então para esse seu caso, não dará problema em forma alguma,

Comment: Acho que entendi (seu comentário, porque o funcionamento do `SimpleDateFormat` ainda me confunde.). E se o usuário está num país que a exibição devia ser "MM-dd-yy", vai funcionar? Ah, atualizei a pergunta, inclusive com o quebra-galho que vou usar se não conseguir resolver a termo.

Comment: @ReneFreak se você definir o formato da sua saída como `MM-dd-yy` e inserir um local fixo, sempre, eu digo sempre, ele vai gravar naquele formato do local quem que você está definindo. Para a exibição, primeiro você vai converter aquela sua string resgatada do banco no formato Date, e aí sim você pode aplicar o formato da região. Porém a princípio você tem que converter para Date, que o tratamento o próprio SO faz.

Comment: @ReneFreak para te dar mais confiança, faça você mesmo um teste, alterando o idioma de sua aplicação.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52557/discussion-between-rene-freak-and-ack-lay).